# Problem migrating custom open api generator from 4.3.1 to 6.5.0 [JAVA - SpringCodegen] #15484

Tags: java, spring, openapi-generator, java-17, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

###### Description

Hi everyone I was migrating plugin for open api from 4.3.1 to latest version 6.5.0.

I has a custom project that use or Extends SpringCodegen for generate my classes of my spring projects. I am migrating the plugin in pom dependencies but I had some errors, I was trying solver that but I can't see what is the reason probably I need configure or add some overrides for use this new version of SpringCodegen or Probably update the mustaches of spring language.

###### openapi-generator version

6.5.0

###### OpenAPI declaration file content or url

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: Simple API
  description: A simple API to illustrate OpenAPI concepts

servers:
  - url: https://example.io/v1

components:
  securitySchemes:
    BasicAuth:
      type: http
      scheme: basic
security:
  - BasicAuth: []

paths:
  /artists:
    get:
      description: Returns a list of artists
      #  ----- Added lines  ----------------------------------------
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Successfully returned a list of artists
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  type: object
                  required:
                    - username
                  properties:
                    artist_name:
                      type: string
                    artist_genre:
                      type: string
                    albums_recorded:
                      type: integer
                    username:
                      type: string

        '400':
          description: Invalid request
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: object
                properties:
                  message:
                    type: string
      #  ---- /Added lines  ----------------------------------------
```

###### Command line used for generation

I am using maven 3.8.1

JDK 17 Temurin, spring boot 3, open api plugin 6.5.0

###### Steps to reproduce

I had this error when I compile the project.

I change from supportingFile.templateFile() to supportingFile.getTemplateFile() because the new version of plugin has this feature in 6.5.0

This fragment is of my class that  @Override method "processOpts" of SpringCodegen

```
supportingFiles.removeIf(supportingFile -> "openapi2SpringBoot.mustache"
        .equals(supportingFile.getTemplateFile())
        && "OpenAPI2SpringBoot.java".equals(supportingFile.getDestinationFilename()));
supportingFiles.add(new SupportingFile("myApplication.mustache",
        (sourceFolder + File.separator + basePackage)
                .replace(".", File.separator), "MyApplication.java"));
```

Log error:

```
unexpected error in Open-API generation

java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate supporting file 'SupportingFile[templateFile='openapi2SpringBoot.mustache', folder='src/main/java/com/myproject/project/services/cross/accessentitlement', destinationFilename='OpenApiGeneratorApplication.java', canOverwrite=true]'
    at org.openapitools.codegen.DefaultGenerator.generateSupportingFiles (DefaultGenerator.java:755)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.DefaultGenerator.generate (DefaultGenerator.java:933)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.plugin.CodeGenMojo.execute (CodeGenMojo.java:870)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:370)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:299)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:963)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:296)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:199)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: org.openapitools.codegen.templating.TemplateNotFoundException: openapi2SpringBoot.mustache
    at org.openapitools.codegen.TemplateManager.getFullTemplateFile (TemplateManager.java:54)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.TemplateManager.getFullTemplateContents (TemplateManager.java:72)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.templating.MustacheEngineAdapter.compileTemplate (MustacheEngineAdapter.java:63)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.TemplateManager.write (TemplateManager.java:163)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.DefaultGenerator.processTemplateToFile (DefaultGenerator.java:1072)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.DefaultGenerator.processTemplateToFile (DefaultGenerator.java:1059)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.DefaultGenerator.generateSupportingFiles (DefaultGenerator.java:747)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.DefaultGenerator.generate (DefaultGenerator.java:933)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.plugin.CodeGenMojo.execute (CodeGenMojo.java:870)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:370)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:299)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:963)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:296)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:199)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
[ERROR] 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate supporting file 'SupportingFile[templateFile='openapi2SpringBoot.mustache', folder='src/main/java/com/myproject/project/services/cross/accessentitlement', destinationFilename='OpenApiGeneratorApplication.java', canOverwrite=true]'
    at org.openapitools.codegen.DefaultGenerator.generateSupportingFiles (DefaultGenerator.java:755)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.DefaultGenerator.generate (DefaultGenerator.java:933)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.plugin.CodeGenMojo.execute (CodeGenMojo.java:870)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:370)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:299)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:963)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:296)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:199)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: org.openapitools.codegen.templating.TemplateNotFoundException: openapi2SpringBoot.mustache
    at org.openapitools.codegen.TemplateManager.getFullTemplateFile (TemplateManager.java:54)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.TemplateManager.getFullTemplateContents (TemplateManager.java:72)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.templating.MustacheEngineAdapter.compileTemplate (MustacheEngineAdapter.java:63)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.TemplateManager.write (TemplateManager.java:163)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.DefaultGenerator.processTemplateToFile (DefaultGenerator.java:1072)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.DefaultGenerator.processTemplateToFile (DefaultGenerator.java:1059)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.DefaultGenerator.generateSupportingFiles (DefaultGenerator.java:747)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.DefaultGenerator.generate (DefaultGenerator.java:933)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.plugin.CodeGenMojo.execute (CodeGenMojo.java:870)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:370)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:299)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:963)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:296)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:199)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
```

###### Related issues/PRs

No

###### Suggest a fix/enhancement